# How to use typescript interface property with the margin property?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

i have  a Label component which is a span tag and accepts the props weight, and size and is like below,

```
interface Props {
    weight?: 200 | 400 | 500 | 700 | 900;
}

const Label = styled.span<Props>`
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: ${p => p.weight || 200};
`;
```

Now i use it in other component and there i need to add margin-right to the Label component so like below,

```
render = () => {
    return (
        <Label 
            weight={400}>
            without using margin-right
        </Label>
        <Label
            weight={700} 
            margin-right={5px} //here i want to add margin-right
        </Label>
    )
}
```

How can i modify the Label component such that it accepts the margin-right property or better even to add margin property with four values something like margin = {0 0 0 5}px;

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to updated your `Props` to the following:

```
interface Props {
    margin?: string
    mb?: string
    ml?: string
    mr?: string
    mt?: string
    weight?: 200 | 400 | 500 | 700 | 900;
}
```

Note: that `mb` will represent `margin-bottom` and so on...

Then update your `Label` as follows:

```
const Label = styled.span<Props>`
    font-weight: ${p => p.weight || 200};
    margin: ${p => p.margin ? margin : 0};

    ${p => p.mb ? `margin-bottom: ${mb};` : ''}
    ${p => p.ml ? `margin-left: ${ml};` : ''}
    ${p => p.mr ? `margin-right: ${mr};` : ''}
    ${p => p.mt ? `margin-top: ${mt};` : ''}
`;
```

Then finally to implement it you can do something like this:

```
<Label
  weight={700} 
  mr="5px"
</Label>
```

You can use `margin` or `mb`, `ml`, `mr` and `mt`. If you use both `margin` and `mb`. The `mb` value will override the bottom value for `margin`.

Remember, implement it like this `mr="5px"` or `mr={"5px"}`, not this:  `mr={5px}`.